How to query channels.editAdmin using TdLib .NET C#?
There is a .NET C# project. The TdLib nuget package is connected to it.
Please tell me how I can execute the request: https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.editAdmin using this library?
To be honest, I don’t understand at all how to use this documentation. I couldn’t find any examples for .NET C#.
If I understand correctly, there are several options for executing queries:
//Using strongly typed APIs example
    using TdLib;
    
    var client = new TdClient();
    TdApi.Ok ok = await client.ExecuteAsync(new TdApi.SetAuthenticationPhoneNumber
    {
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber
    });

And
//Using json client
    using TdLib;
    
    var json = ""; // json data
    double timeout = 1.0; // 1 second
    
    using (var jsonClient = new TdJsonClient())
    {
        jsonClient.Send(json); // send request
        var result = jsonClient.Receive(timeout); // receive response
    }

The actual question is: how to execute the channels.editAdmin request using the first or second option?
UPD:
I found an example code for calling this method in JS:
// make the bot an admin of the channel
            const makeAdmin: Api.TypeUpdates = await client.invoke(
              new Api.channels.EditAdmin({
                channel: new Api.InputChannel({
                  channelId: channelId as bigInt.BigInteger,
                  accessHash: accessHash as bigInt.BigInteger,
                }),
                userId: '@BotNameHere',
                adminRights: new Api.ChatAdminRights({
                  changeInfo: true,
                  postMessages: true,
                  editMessages: true,
                  deleteMessages: true,
                  banUsers: true,
                  inviteUsers: true,
                  pinMessages: true,
                  addAdmins: true,
                  anonymous: false,
                  manageCall: true,
                  other: false,
                }),
                rank: 'Administrator',
              })
            );
            if (makeAdmin instanceof Api.Updates) {
              logger.info('Bot is now an admin of the channel');
            }
          }

But it’s still unclear how to adapt it to my situation.
I've tried to investigate telegram api documentation. But it's still unclear.
